# Debian Kernel Panic Crash - Help Needed

Tags: debian, crash, kernel-panic

This remote server was not responsive via SSH (timed out) and the screen showed this:

[image]

I can not tell what those messages are about. They came in repeatedly every couple of seconds. [Here is also a short video on Imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9xdCT.jpg).

The device has been turned off and rebooted, afterwards everything worked as expected again. This has happened once before, a couple of months ago.

It is a Debian Stretch system hosting a Nextcloud instance in a Docker environment, and that is pretty much it.

What is this about? How can I investigate what happened to the system? How could possible fixes look like?

Comment: Hmm, can you try to journalctl -xe and what it say.

Comment: The output of `journalctl -xe` is [here](https://dump.elektrat.de/9hyhtkbgmg8emanq.txt) but it only starts after the reboot. How can I read older logs?